# Reverse Root Solution

Tags: performance, memory-management, go

Solved one of the [easiest problems](https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001) from acm.timus.ru.

> [1001. Reverse Root](https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001)
>
> The input stream contains a set of integer numbers Aᵢ (0 ≤ Aᵢ ≤ 10¹⁸).
> The numbers are separated by any number of spaces and line breaks.
> A size of the input stream does not exceed 256 KB.
>
> For each number Aᵢ from the last one till the first one you should
> output its square root. Each square root should be printed in a
> separate line with at least four digits after decimal point.

I would like to know why my solution is relatively slow (execution time is 1s) and uses so much memory (7 072 KB)? Compared to C++: 0.093s  and 408 KB of memory.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "math"

var a []int64

func main() {
    for {
        var x int64
        k, _ := fmt.Scan(&x)
        if k != 1 {
            break
        }
        a = append(a,x)
    }
    n := len(a)

    for n > 0 {
        n--
        fmt.Printf("%.4f\n", math.Sqrt(float64(a[n])))
    }
}
```

Is the significantly larger resource consumption due to garbage collection and imported libraries or just my code is inefficient?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Links can rot. Please include the necessary info in your question. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

A benchmark is a scientific experiment.

An essential feature of a scientific experiment is that it be reproducible.

You do not provide any C++ code. You do provide some Go code. You do not define your methods for measuring CPU and memory. You provide some undefined CPU and memory measurements.

Your Go code looks inefficient.

---

> [1001. Reverse
> Root](https://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001)
>
> The input stream contains a set of integer numbers Aᵢ (0 ≤ Aᵢ ≤ 10¹⁸).
> The numbers are separated by any number of spaces and line breaks. A
> size of the input stream does not exceed 256 KB.
>
> For each number Aᵢ from the last one till the first one you should
> output its square root. Each square root should be printed in a
> separate line with at least four digits after decimal point.

---

Compare my Go code (revroot.go) to your slower Go code (revroot.ivan.go):

```
$ ls -s -h revroot.in.data
256K revroot.in.data
$

$ go build revroot.go && time ./revroot < revroot.in.data > revroot.out.data
real    0m0.007s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.000s
$ go build revroot.go && time ./revroot < revroot.in.data > revroot.out.data
real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s
$ ls -s -h revroot.out.data
208K revroot.out.data
$

$ go build revroot.ivan.go && time ./revroot.ivan < revroot.in.data > revroot.out.data
real    0m0.251s
user    0m0.141s
sys     0m0.113s
$ go build revroot.ivan.go && time ./revroot.ivan < revroot.in.data > revroot.out.data
real    0m0.245s
user    0m0.147s
sys     0m0.100s
$ ls -s -h revroot.out.data
208K revroot.out.data
$
```

---

`revroot.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func RevRoot(in io.Reader, out io.Writer) error {
    var a []float64

    s := bufio.NewScanner(in)
    s.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for s.Scan() {
        i, err := strconv.ParseUint(s.Text(), 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        a = append(a, math.Sqrt(float64(i)))
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    w, ok := out.(*bufio.Writer)
    if !ok {
        w = bufio.NewWriter(out)
    }
    defer w.Flush()
    buf := make([]byte, 0, 32)
    for n := len(a) - 1; n >= 0; n-- {
        buf = strconv.AppendFloat(buf[:0], a[n], 'f', 4, 64)
        buf = append(buf, '\n')
        _, err := w.Write(buf)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    err := w.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := RevRoot(os.Stdin, os.Stdout)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
    }
    return
}
```

`revroot.ivan.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "math"

var a []int64

func main() {
    for {
        var x int64
        k, _ := fmt.Scan(&x)
        if k != 1 {
            break
        }
        a = append(a, x)
    }
    n := len(a)

    for n > 0 {
        n--
        fmt.Printf("%.4f\n", math.Sqrt(float64(a[n])))
    }
}
```

---

In Go, to measure performance we run benchmarks. We exclude I/O and other OS functions.

```
$ go test revroot_test.go revroot.go -run=! -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkRevRoot-4   249   4775861 ns/op   833577 B/op   13202 allocs/op
$
```

My `RevRoot` function takes 4,775,861 nanoseconds (0.004,775,861 seconds) for 13,177 square roots.

`revroot_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkRevRoot(b *testing.B) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, 256*1024))
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(42))
    for {
        buf.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(r.Int()))
        buf.WriteString("\n")
        if buf.Len() > 256*1024-256 {
            break
        }
    }
    data := buf.String()

    b.ResetTimer()
    for N := 0; N < b.N; N++ {
        err := RevRoot(strings.NewReader(data), ioutil.Discard)
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```